# Как поставить в поток функцию из другой асинхронной discord.py

Tags: python, многопоточность, асинхронность, discord.py, pthread

У меня есть асинхронная функция `A` которая вызывается по event `on_raw_reaction_add`, в ней я пытаюсь поставить в поток другую асинхронную функцию `B` через модуль `threading`. Функция `B` выполняет отправку сообщений в канал из своих аргументов.

Я плохо знаком с корутинами и потоками, но как я понимаю поставить в поток можно только асинхронную функцию. Я пробую это сделать в функции `A` без использования `await` исходя из логики прерывания, и получаю ошибку - `RntimeWarning: coroutine 'FarmZat' was never awaited`. Тогда я подставляю `await` к `FarmZ.start()` и при выполнении функции `A` снова получаю ошибку `TypeError: object NoneType can't be used in 'await' expression`.

Что я делаю не правильно и как нужно поставить функцию в поток? Буду благодарен за помощь, даже за ссылку в документацию.

**A**:

```
async def CreateFarmChannel(member: discord.Member):
    guild = bot.get_guild(880008097370865706)
    category = discord.utils.get(guild.categories, name="Фермы")


    channel = await guild.create_text_channel(f'⛏{member.name}', category=category)
    await channel.set_permissions(guild.default_role, read_messages=False)
    await channel.set_permissions(member, read_messages=True, send_messages=True)

    FarmZ = Thread(target=FarmZat, args=(member, channel))
    FarmZ.start()
```

**B:**

```
async def FarmZat(member: discord.Member, channel):
    await channel.send("Канал создан")
```

Comment: ` поставить в поток можно только асинхронную функцию` - нет. Только обычную. Но вы просто так не сможете вызывать из другого потока асинхронные функции (типа channel.send). Лучше вам описать изначальную проблему, потому что то, что вы делаете - это, возможно, неправильный способ решить какую то (нам неизвестуную) задачу. Чтоб подсказать вам как решить ее, нужно чтоб вы ее описали в вопросе.

Comment: Roman Konoval, спасибо за поправку. Я пробовал запускать свою функцию без `async`, но тогда я не мог отправлять сообщения без `await` я получал ошибку

`bot.py:374: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'Messageable.send' was never awaited`

Answer (score 0):

Не очень понял суть вопроса, но попробуйте это:

```
import asyncio
async def CreateFarmChannel(member: discord.Member):
    guild = bot.get_guild(880008097370865706)
    category = discord.utils.get(guild.categories, name="Фермы")


    channel = await guild.create_text_channel(f'⛏{member.name}', category=category)
    await channel.set_permissions(guild.default_role, read_messages=False)
    await channel.set_permissions(member, read_messages=True, send_messages=True)

    def FarmZat1(member, channel):
        asyncio.run(FarmZat(member, channel))
    FarmZ = Thread(target=FarmZat1, args=(member, channel))
    FarmZ.start()
```

Comment: Пожалуй я действительно плохо описал проблему, я хочу поставить в поток функцию что бы бот мог параллельно выполнять действия. А `await` в моем понимании приостанавливает процесс выполнения программы что бы выполнить мою функцию, не позволяя боту выполнять другие команды.

Comment: Я отредактировал ответ, попробуйте так

Comment: Я попробовал запустить код и получил ошибку - `"Timeout context manager should be used " "inside a task" RuntimeError: Timeout context manager should be used inside a task`